# Killing MailCatcher: Something's using port 1025

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman, mailcatcher

I'm trying to run "foreman start" for a rails app however this error message is preventing me from running the foreman properly:

> ~~> ERROR: Something's using port 1025. Are you already running
>   MailCatcher?

I've tried killing the PID, going to the web interface to quit the program and also...restarting the comp.  Does anybody know how to remedy this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you running an NFS? [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Registered_ports), NFS will use that port.

Comment: @MisterDood you right. I'm using NFS alongside my vagrant box and when deactivate the NFS syncing, the error message went off. Pretty weird given I've done this same conf in a MBP (same vagrant box).

Answer (score 49):

In OSX, run the following in a shell:

```
sudo lsof -nP -iTCP:1025 -sTCP:LISTEN
```

The expected output of this command is a process, which is listening on port 1025:

```
ruby    43841 youruserid    9u  IPv4 0x6a1610da80bb9b4f      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:1025 (LISTEN)
```

In the output above, the 2nd value is the process ID.   Then, to kill the offending process (substitute in the correct PID):

```
sudo kill 43841
```

Comment: What about if the process keeps rebooting with a new PID everytime you try to kill it? Any ideas?

Comment: Then there is likely some other process running that is ensuring that mailcatcher is on if it is not already on.

Comment: Yeah it seems like that was the case. Also the problem for me wasn't the mail catcher process but the code sending an email, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Use quit option on top right in mail catcher browser window

Comment: Only this answer worked for me on Mac.

Clicking 'Quit' from 127.0.0.1:1080 web interface simply didn't work for me on Mac.

Answer (score 19):

[MailCatcher](https://mailcatcher.me/) launches both SMTP and HTTP servers.

### When you start MailCatcher in a terminal you'll see the following output:

```bash
$ mailcatcher
Starting MailCatcher
==> smtp://127.0.0.1:1025
==> http://127.0.0.1:1080
*** MailCatcher runs as a daemon by default. Go to the web interface to quit.
```

*See the last line in the output when starting MailCatcher?*

### If you attempt to start MailCatcher if it's already running you'll see:

```bash
$ mailcatcher
Starting MailCatcher
~~> ERROR: Something's using port 1025. Are you already running MailCatcher?
```

### How to quit Mailcatcher:

1. Open the `http` url (http://127.0.0.1:1080) in your browser.

   **Note:** the port may be different than `1080`. If so, you'll have to use that port. If you don't know it, you'll have to use one of the other answers here to kill the running process.
2. In the top right corner of the page that opens, you'll see a "Quit" link.

[image: How to Quit MailCatcher]

Comment: how to quit if i cannot access the http url. (running in a remote server)

Comment: i found the answer
`sudo lsof -nP -iTCP:1025 -sTCP:LISTEN

`sudo kill <PID>

Comment: I use the quit button and refresh the page, VIOLA it's still there running.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using linux, you should be able to see what program is using a certain port using the netstat command. To see if port 1025 is in use, run this from the command line:

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep :1025
```

Here is a useful reference: 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/

Comment: I've executed the command with lsof|grep :1025.  Killed th e PID with kill -9 PID.  However I'm still getting the error.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by starting mailcatcher on a different port:
`mailcatcher --smtp-port 1026`

And changing the following in `config/development.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  ...
  port: 1026,
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm on Windows, it doesn't help with port `1026` or `1027` etc. But it lead me in the right direction. Didn't think of just simply changing the port. It works with `--smtp-port 30000` for me, Windows 7.
Found it here https://block81.com/articles/test-emails-locally-with-mailcatcher

Answer (score 4):

get the process id's of the ports mailcatcher is using

```
lsof -i tcp:1080 
lsof -i tcp:1025
```

kill em:

```
kill 37747 
kill 35647
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid that type of situation use mailcatcher in a container. You can find few in docker hub, here is [my cut](https://github.com/spaquet/alpinemailcatcher).

Answer (score 0):

Try `launchctl remove me.mailcatcher`

Answer (score 0):

A good advice. If you already have somehow "postfix" configured or running just stop it in order to get the mails in "Mail Catcher"

```
sudo systemctl stop postfix
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here in case it helps someone else.

I made the mistake of visiting http://localhost:1025/, whereas I needed to be at http://localhost:1080/.

Go to http://localhost:1080/ and hopefully mailcatcher is running as expected

Answer (score 0):

Another way to kill MailCatcher in this situation, if you are using a Mac:

Manually stop all ruby processes that you are running locally, and then open Activity Monitor, by pressing `Command + Space` (to bring up Spotlight) and type "Activity Monitor" to find and open the application.

In Activity Monitor, sort the processes by `Process Name`.  Look for any processes named `ruby` that remain running:

[image: Image showing processed named 'ruby' in Activity Monitor]

Click on any process that you are interested in killing, and click the `Stop Process` button at the top of the window.

[image: Image showing button image with "X" labeled "Stop"]

After manually stopping all `ruby` processes and then killing any remaining `ruby` processes in this manner, you should then be able to run MailCatcher successfully.